# How to setup re-stream video server?

Tags: video, software-rec, streaming

At church we have a computer that takes all video inputs and makes one with mixer, etc. Then we have internet connection that supports up to 1mb/s upload (actual upload speed).

We have been using ustream for streaming videos but decided to upgrade.

We have a budget of $4000 for everything (including 2-3 IP cameras) and then around 100 every month for datacenter.

Plan is to stream highest possible quality to server which will be located in data center. Then from the server we can stream low, medium, high quality video streams.

My question is what software can re-stream video in different qualities? Or just how to re-stream video? What software to use?

Added:
We plan to stream 720 from church and then 480 and 720 from server. 1080 will be streamed in future.

Answer (score 1):

For a server, [Red5 Media Server](http://www.red5.org) would do what you need if you know Java.

Since you are already outputting to ustream you have a Flash encoder.  The Flash media encoder is also capable of outputting multiple bitrates and resolutions.